# How to Convert Date Format to different pattern in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, date

I want to convert Date Format from this `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`

to like this `yyyy-MM-dd`

**this is my data json right know from redis**

```
{
   "bannerId":4,
   "bannerName":"banner test test 2 123"
   "startDate":"Mon Sep 02 00:00:00 WIB 2019",
   "endDate":"Sat Sep 28 00:00:00 WIB 2019"
}
```

and i want to convert **startDate** and **endDate** like json below

**and json ouput that i want**

```
{
   "bannerId":4,
   "bannerName":"banner test test 2 123"
   "startDate":"2019-09-02",
   "endDate":"2019-09-28"
}
```

so far I've tried it, but failed..
show error like this 
**`failed Unparseable date: \"2019-09-02\`**

.

and this is my code

**Banner.java**

```
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class Banner {

    private Integer bannerId;
    private String bannerName;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", timezone = "Asia/Jakarta")
    private Date startDate;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", timezone = "Asia/Jakarta")
    private Date endDate;
}
```

**BannerController.java**

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
listRedis = bannerService.loadBannerRedis(Constant.DVC_BANNER_MOBILE, Constant.LOC_BANNER_HOME, Constant.PST_BANNER_MAIN);
    for (Banner banner : listRedis) {

         banner.setStartDate(
              new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(
                  Convert.convertDate(dateFormat.format(banner.getStartDate()))));
    }
```

**Convert.java**

```
public static String convertDate(String dd) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(dd);     

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        String formatedDate = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
        return formatedDate;
}
```

so, i need solution what im to do??

Comment: where do you get this first json at?

Comment: try this SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        final Date parse = sdf.parse(banner.getStartDate().toString());
        sdf.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `LocalDateTime` for this , you should avoid using legacy `Date` class

```
 String str = "Mon Sep 02 00:00:00 WIB 2019";
            LocalDateTime parse = LocalDateTime.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"));
            System.out.println(parse);
            DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String format = parse.format(dateTimeFormatter);
            System.out.println(format);  
            // out-put 2019-09-02
```

You can also use same on `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use here. It cannot represent a moment as it lacks the context of a time zone or offset. The string input indicates a time zone. So your are ignoring valuable information.

Comment: yes , you are correct, i was just focusing on formatting

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime
        .parse(
                "Mon Sep 02 00:00:00 WIB 2019" ,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , Locale.US )
        )
        .toLocalDate()
```

> 2019-09-02

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

[Define a formatting pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale)) to match your input. Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms to use in parsing name of month, name of day, and so on.

```
String input = "Mon Sep 02 00:00:00 WIB 2019";
Locale locale = Locale.US;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , locale );
```

Parse.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

Dump to console, using standard ISO 8601 format for generated text, wisely extending the standard to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
System.out.println( "zdt = " + zdt );
```

> zdt = 2019-09-02T00:00+07:00[Asia/Jakarta]

You want the date only, without time-of-day and without the time zone.

But you must understand that for any given moment **the date varies around the world** by time zone. So at any moment it can be "tomorrow" in Tokyo Japan while still "yesterday" in Toledo Ohio US.

Do you want the date as seen in Indonesia?

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Or do you want the date as seen in UTC?

```
LocalDate ld = 
    zdt
    .toOffsetDateTime()
    .withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC )
    .toLocalDate() 
;
```

Then generate your desired output string whose format happens to comply with the ISO 8601 standard format used by default in `LocalDate::toString`.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

Tip: Educate the publisher of your data about:

- The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defining date-time formats to use when exchanging date-time values as text.
- The wisdom of generally communicating moments in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds) rather than a particular time zone.
- Real time zone names are in the format of `Continent/Region`, *not* 2-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `WIB`, `CST`, or `IST`.